# How do I align enumerate items inside empty description?

Tags: lists, enumerate, description

I have an `enumerate` list inside an empty `description` item.

The minimal file is,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [A Label:]

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A1.
  \item A2.
  \item A3.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{description}



\end{document}
```

The problem is, A1 comes after the colon (:). As you can see here,

[image]

But I want A1 in a new line, with 1. aligned with 2.

I tried putting a `\relax` in the empty `description` item. Nothing was improved.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This must be a duplicate but I didn't see a good question to reference after a quick search so the easiest way without doing any complicated redefinitions of latex list code is

```
  \item [A Label:]\mbox{}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
```

where the `\mbox` forces a paragraph start so the nested list indents normally.

Comment: Thanks. Worked flawlessly. I did some searching before asking the question. I did not find any.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this approach may separate the two environments (description and enumerate) at a break page, in such a way that `A Label:` will be placed at the end of the page while the list `1., 2., 3.` will move to the next page. What would be a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @pluton using `\\*` rather than `\\ ` would strongly discourage a page break

Answer (score 6):

You could also just do

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[]
\item A1.
\item A2.
\item A3.
\end{enumerate}
```

instead of the above. Works equally well (and looks better in my opinion).

Comment: Indeed it works. Though I was skeptical before trying it out. Nice solution.

Comment: This is better since (unlike the accepted answer) you don't have to adjust space manually.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution I found for this was just `\hfill` at the end of the line.

```
\begin{description}
  \item[First] \hfill
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item A
      \item B
      \item C
    \end{enumerate}
  \item[Second] The second thing
  \item[Third] The third thing
\end{description}
```